# How to use my local mouse to control remote desktop

Tags: linux, windows, mouse, hardware, remote-desktop

I want to develop a program on both Windows and Linux that can use the mouse that's being physically plugged into my machine to control the mouse event in the remote desktop which is a Windows OS.

I am a beginner so I would like to know how will this work, what do I need to learn before I get started.

For now, I am imagining that I need to firstly build a connection between my local device and a server and stay connected during the whole session using some kind of protocol. Then I need to connect my mouse to the remote mouse somehow through the driver? (Correct me if I am wrong).

This question is aimed to get some general idea of what components should this program have and what I have to learn before get started.

Thanks!

Comment: why re-invent the wheel? that's exactly what VNC does.

Comment: Not trying to reinvent the wheel. Just want to know how the wheel works.

Comment: well, vnc's basically an open protocol. there's gotta be open source implementations that you can grab and poke around the guts to see what they're doing.

Comment: To be honest, this is a bit like deciding to learn engineering and starting out by trying to design a skyscraper.  Off-topic here as it is too broad.  But you could start by looking at the rdesktop project, which implements the *client* end of a Remote Desktop connection (the server end being already built into Windows).